# Is there a way to search for comments in a pull request reviewed by a given user on GitHub?

Tags: github

Is there a way to search for comments in a pull request reviewed by a given user on GitHub?

On GitHub, I remember some insightful comments made by a previous developer on some issue with mutations, but I can't find it. Is there a way to search for comments made by a given user?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`gh pr view`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_view), the GitHub CLI command, to view a Pull Request.
No clone necessary. Just [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) first.

For instance:

- `gh pr view 385 -c -R apache/httpd` list all comments in [`apache/httpd` PR 385](https://github.com/apache/httpd/pull/385)
- `gh pr view 385 -c -R apache/httpd --json comments` focuses on comments.
- `gh pr view 385 -c -R apache/httpd --json comments --jq ".comments | .[] | select(.author.login == \"Mrida\" and (.body | tostring | contains(\"insight\")))"` (Windows CMD syntax)
  That would select only comments from Mrida, with the word insight in it.

  A Linux syntax would be:

  `gh pr view 385 -c -R apache/httpd --json comments --jq '.comments | .[] | select(.author.login == "Mrida" and (.body | tostring | contains("insight")))'`

Result:

```json
{
  "author": {
    "login": "Mrida"
  },
  "authorAssociation": "NONE",
  "body": "Hello @ylavic, I really appreciate any insights or feedback you might have about this PR.",
  "createdAt": "2023-10-12T09:39:24Z",
  "id": "IC_kwDOAAMib85o3GpH",
  "includesCreatedEdit": false,
  "isMinimized": false,
  "minimizedReason": "",
  "reactionGroups": [],
  "url": "https://github.com/apache/httpd/pull/385#issuecomment-1759275591",
  "viewerDidAuthor": false
}
{
  "author": {
    "login": "Mrida"
  },
  "authorAssociation": "NONE",
  "body": "Hello @icing, as this PR will be closed soon, I really appreciate any insights or feedback you might have about it.",
  "createdAt": "2023-10-16T08:22:20Z",
  "id": "IC_kwDOAAMib85pJA7O",
  "includesCreatedEdit": false,
  "isMinimized": false,
  "minimizedReason": "",
  "reactionGroups": [],
  "url": "https://github.com/apache/httpd/pull/385#issuecomment-1763970766",
  "viewerDidAuthor": false
}
```

---

If you do not want all the fields, you can add the ones you need.
For instance, `body` and `createdAt`:

`gh pr view 385 -c -R apache/httpd --json "comments" --jq ".comments | .[] | select(.author.login == \"Mrida\" and (.body | tostring | contains(\"insight\"))) | {body: .body, createdAt: .createdAt}"`

```json
{
  "body": "Hello @ylavic, I really appreciate any insights or feedback you might have about this PR.",
  "createdAt": "2023-10-12T09:39:24Z"
}
{
  "body": "Hello @icing, as this PR will be closed soon, I really appreciate any insights or feedback you might have about it.",
  "createdAt": "2023-10-16T08:22:20Z"
}
```

---

This also applies to annotated code in a PR, using `latestReviews`:

`gh pr view 385 -R apache/httpd --json latestReviews --jq ".latestReviews | .[] | select(.author.login == \"covener\" and (.body | tostring | contains(\"bump\"))) | {body: .body, submittedAt: .submittedAt}"`

That returns any code review annotated by `covener`, with the word `bump` in it:

```json
{
"body": "If you add fields to mod_proxy.h I think you must bump include/ap_mmn.h as well, please review the history of that file\r\n\r\nno comment on the core of the change here or what regressed, hopefully others can comment.",
"submittedAt": "2023-10-16T11:38:51Z"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But I am mainly using the GitHub web view for checking pull requests (i.e. `https://github.com/<organization>/<project>/pull/<pr number>`), do you have hints how to do it there?

Comment: @Matt No, I don't think this is supported by the GitHub web view, which is why I mention this alternative. No clone needed. The [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) allows for more detailed queries than the GitHub web view.

Comment: What I found (and as described by @bg2094) is to type into the search field on screen `repo:<organization>/<project> commenter:<userid>`, but then the search isn't limited to the pull request, it searches globally in the project. That is described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-commenter). Any ideas how to limit it to specific PR? Is there a qualifier to specify a PR number?

Comment: One more question: The command "gh" seems to be unavailable on my PC (maybe because I am using it through PyCharm Terminal): I am getting `The term 'gh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.` But GitHub is working from the PyCharm IDE (I can push, pull etc).

Comment: @Matt The GitHub CLI `gh` needs to be [installed first](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation), and in your PATH, for you to use it in your shell.

Comment: On https://cli.github.com/ I found I need to install GH via `choco install gh` (admin shell), which worked fine, I was also able to authenticate by token, but then `gh pr view 385` didn't work (I assume 385 is the PR number) - it gave me `failed to run git: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git` Any thoughts?

Comment: @Matt My example in the answer above does not mention `gh pr view 385`. It mentions `gh pr view 385 -c -R apache/httpd`. Meaning, it specifies the repository that issue refers to.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Now it returned entries. I used `gh pr view <PRNUMBER> -c -R <ORGANIZATION>/<REPO> --json comments --jq ".comments | .[] | select(.author.login == \"<USERID>\")"` to get all comments of user with <USERID>. But it seems only the author of the PR is regarded by `.author.login` - what if I want to see all comments of USERID regardless of his/her role in the PR?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256235/discussion-between-vonc-and-matt).

Comment: This is awesome. However it only seems to return unresolved/unminimized comments. Is there any way to include resolved comments in the search as well?

Comment: @JamesCrosswell Not sure. It depends if the resolved status is somehow visible in `gh pr view <PRNUMBER> -c -R <ORGANIZATION>/<REPO> --json comments` output. If not... then no (at least, not using this).

Answer (score -2):

In the search bar use `commenter:<username>` in the repo you want to search in. This will take you to the search results page. On that page, on the left navigation bar select `Pull requests` and this should return all the pull requests with comments from that specific user.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: No, it does not answer the question. This returns list of pull request, not list of comments.